# BigQuery Restrict table drop

Tags: google-bigquery

I was trying to create a role in big query that allows the user to create/delete datasets and tables on their own, but denies the deletion of tables that the user didn't create, so far I got the first part covered by creating a custom role that has

```
bigquery.datasets.create    
bigquery.datasets.delete    
bigquery.datasets.get
```

But when I try to restrict the drop, I don't know how to deal with this, if I remove bigquery.tables.delete, I will avoid the users to delete even their tables, so far I got the functions for tables like this

```
bigquery.tables.create 
bigquery.tables.delete
bigquery.tables.export  
bigquery.tables.get     
bigquery.tables.getData
```

So is there a way in which I can do this?

Comment: You can submit a feature request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559654

Comment: @RaizenD1 please let us know if you had filled in a Feature Request and if yes, provide us with the link.

Comment: I did, the request is here https://issuetracker.google.com/u/3/issues/172933215